# Convert a byte[] to a BufferedImage

Tags: java, byte, bufferedimage

I'm having problem to convert a byte[] to a BufferedImage. I know that there are a lot of posts and questions-answers, but I just can1t see why my code is wrong. (Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!)

Thanks!

```
try {
        String hex = "57656c636f6d652c206d7920667269656e642e";
        byte[] im = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(hex);
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(im);
        BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(in);
        ImageIO.write(bImageFromConvert, "jpg", new File("c:/welcome.jpg"));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
```

Comment: Ok, so I decoded the hex string and it says "Welcome, my friend." ImageIO.read() reads files like JPGs and PNGs. What did you expect it to do with a string of ascii?

Comment: To convert text into an image you need to create a bufferedimage of the required size, fill the background as required, set a color, set a font and then draw the string on it. you cant just turn text into an image with a few lines of code (not with the java standard library anyway)

Comment: You can't see why your code is wrong? How could you even imagine your code was right?

Comment: Also, *if* your hex string contained a JPEG, there's no need to decode it to a `BufferedImage` and encode it again. Just write the parsed bytes (`im`) directly to the file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to use

```
File newfile = new File("c:/welcome.jpg"); 
newfile.exists();
```

to check newfile does it exist.

Comment: its failing to write the file because it cant convert "Welcome, my friend." into an image. the premise that  ImageIO.read() will do that is wrong

Answer (score 0):

OK. I did what slipperyseal told and worked. Thanks. The code is below.

```
try {
        Font font = new Font("Arial", 0, 32);
        BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(1, 1, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        FontMetrics fm = img.getGraphics().getFontMetrics(font);
        int width = fm.stringWidth("Welcome, my friend.");
        int height = fm.getHeight();
        int padding = 7;

        BufferedImage bgImage = new BufferedImage(width+padding*2, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics2D drawer = bgImage.createGraphics() ;
        drawer.setBackground(Color.white);
        drawer.clearRect(0,0,(int)width+padding*2,(int)height);
        drawer.setColor(Color.black);
        drawer.setFont(font);
        drawer.drawString("Welcome, my friend.", padding, height-padding);

        ImageIO.write(bgImage, "png", new File("c:/welcome.png"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Is any problem with that code? Like bad practice, ...

Comment: This may work, but I don't see how it's related to the question... This is the answer to "How do I create an image, draw a string to it, and save it as a JPEG?"...